# How to put together centered text and fixed image?

Tags: css

I have a white page with only a 500x250 textbox and an image. The page is fluid.

I'm trying to center the textbox at the center of a page, while having a picture fixed to the bottom left of the screen. I partially achieve this with the following css:

```
.bottom-right { /* used to fix the image to the bottom of the screen */
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

#content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
```

When I vertically resize the window, the image covers the textbox. I would instead like the text to go up.

Comment: by "go up" do you mean "be positioned over the image instead of below" or "on top of the image so that you can still read the text"

Comment: on top of the image so that you can still read the text (as long as there's still space in that margin-top: 50% of the screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need to have the "textbox" always over the image that's fixed on the bottom-right corner.

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/zDtm9/) Example!

**CSS**

```
#content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;          /* this is the key */
    z-index: 1;                  /* this is the key */
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -125px 0 0 -250px;
}
```

---

- CSS [`position:absolute;`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position)

  What this does is to place the element `#content` outside the normal document flow, thus not being affected by other elements or having impact on the layout of later siblings.
- CSS [`z-index:1;`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

  What this does is to move the element up on the document stack, thus placing it over others with a lower value (the default stack level is 0).

See the [CSS absolute and fixed positioning - W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning) for further details.

Comment: this works, but could you please demystify the margin-top and margin-left values? I see how you compute them, but why? I don't follow the logic.

Comment: @simpatico, that's not relevant to the answer, but if you give 50% `top` and `left` the element is moved to the center, and then with minus half the box `width` and `height`, it will be fully centered on its container by its middle point! (don't know if its clear enough, but I'll place a link in a few moments)

Comment: the margins are mystical, but your code solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

1. Use CSS media queries and if the viewport is less than a certain height then change the textbox height or position so the image doesn't cover it.
2. Set a `min-height` around the parent `div` and once its less than a certain height, show a vertical scrollbar.